# html5 local database access with selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I been asked to make a selenium test that checks the local database of html5 and verify that the information in there matches what's being displayed on the screen. This is for a mobile application that can be used on chrome I have everything working as far as selenium working with chrome.Now I am just stuck on trying to find a method that can be used for with selenium that will access the local database storage. There's a interface in selenium html5 packages that DatabaseStorage however I can not figure out how that works or how to use it. The test cases are being written in Java. Thank you all for any help you can provide on this.

I have tried to create a new object of the database storage. which dident work i tried creating a new object of result set also tried doing implements database storage. in the API for database storage it says it a interface but it dose not list a constructor. i not sure how to access a method when there's no constructor for the interface.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So you've got a bunch of problems creating a software suite. I would suggest breaking that into manageable parts and then discussing them individually as necessary. We really dont have the ability to look at all of these technologies on a holistic level especially given how unclear your problems are. Try refining your problems and if your efforts fail you'll have a better question to ask us.

Comment: @GregRehm There is nothing at all wrong with this question.  It's easy to say things you don't understand are meaningless but in reality that is not at all the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 // Database Storage
    private ResultSet executeQuery(String statement, String... param) {

      String databaseName = "'HTML5', '1.0'," 
         +" 'Offline document storage', 100*1024";

      return ((DatabaseStorage) driver).executeSQL(databaseName, statement, (Object[]) param);
    }
```

see Selenium's [HTML5 test](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/common/test/java/org/openqa/selenium/html5/HTML5Test.java?r=10409) for more details.